# Unable to use a chromecast with a WRT160N router running DD-WRT

Tags: android, dd-wrt, chromecast

A few days ago I bought a Chromecast. I did the setup using my phone and it works great when using my phone, tablet or a wifi computer to cast stuff to it but I can't use it from my desktop PC which is connected to the same network through a Linksys wireless router running non-stock FW.

The router is a WRT160N V3 and is running DD-WRT v24 SP2 (yeah, I know it's old but since it works perfectly for what I need it never thought about updating it). The problem I have is that the Chromecast extension for Chrome can't find the device connected to my TV (Message: No Cast Devices Found). The router is *not* running in isolation mode and I have UPnP enabled. I read I need to set some option called IGMP or something like that but I can't find it in the router's WebGUI.

Any idea what I could do to fix this?. Thanks (Sorry for posting in the wrong site first)!.